# How to create a two-step MailChimp signup form?

Tags: ajax, mailchimp, newsletter

How does one go about using the MailChimp API to create a two-step signup process? I'm having a really hard time finding any documentation for this. It should go like this:

**Step 1:**

The website shows a sign up form with just an email field and a subscribe button. Once someone fills out her/his email address and hits 'Subscribe', the email address gets added to the list, and then additional options show up in a modal window (name, location, interests, etc.)

**Step 2:**

At this stage the user has already been added to the mailing list. The user can now choose to fill in the additional fields in the modal window (which will then be added to her/his account), or if he doesn't, then certain default values are added, after which a thank you message is shown.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest that you use a single signup form as you capture your subscribers ... users rarely want to do something in two steps. Make it easy for them to take all the actions they want in one screen.

When you design your form, consider what information is mandatory and what is optional. You will need to think of how you will use the fields, groups, etc later in campaigns.

You can provide default values for many of the fields. You can also specify what message to send for an initial subscription.

Remember, a user is not "subscribed" until they accept the "did you really mean to subscribe" email that is automatically send by MailChimp.